# Related content from JSON & API

Tags: javascript

i have a json returned from an api that shows latest discussions from a forum..

the url that display the json output is like:

```
https://example.com/api/discussions?isApproved=true&exists=true&sort=-lastPostedAt
```

and this is the json output:

```
"links": {
        "first": "http://localhost/flarum/public/api/discussions?isApproved=true\u0026exists=true\u0026sort=-lastPostedAt",
        "next": "http://localhost/flarum/public/api/discussions?isApproved=true\u0026exists=true\u0026sort=-lastPostedAt\u0026page%5Boffset%5D=20"
    },
    "data": [
        {
            "type": "discussions",
            "id": "46",
            "attributes": {
                "title": "footer",
                "slug": "46-footer",
                "commentCount": 1,
                "participantCount": 1,
                "createdAt": "2021-09-20T07:14:18+00:00",
                "lastPostedAt": "2021-09-20T07:14:18+00:00",
                "lastPostNumber": 1,
                "canReply": true,
                "canRename": true,
                "canDelete": true,
                "canHide": true,
                "lastReadAt": "2021-09-20T07:14:20+00:00",
                "lastReadPostNumber": 1,
                "isApproved": true,
                "canTag": true,
                "subscription": null,
                "isLocked": false,
                "canLock": true
            },
            "relationships": { "user": { "data": { "type": "users", "id": "1" } }, "lastPostedUser": { "data": { "type": "users", "id": "1" } }, "tags": { "data": [{ "type": "tags", "id": "2" }] } }
        },
        {
            "type": "discussions",
            "id": "45",
            "attributes": {
                "title": "fhgfhfg",
                "slug": "45-fhgfhfg",
                "commentCount": 2,
                "participantCount": 1,
                "createdAt": "2021-09-19T16:07:37+00:00",
                "lastPostedAt": "2021-09-19T23:04:00+00:00",
                "lastPostNumber": 2,
                "canReply": true,
                "canRename": true,
                "canDelete": true,
                "canHide": true,
                "lastReadAt": "2021-09-19T23:04:02+00:00",
                "lastReadPostNumber": 2,
                "isApproved": true,
                "canTag": true,
                "subscription": null,
                "isLocked": false,
                "canLock": true
            },
            "relationships": { "user": { "data": { "type": "users", "id": "1" } }, "lastPostedUser": { "data": { "type": "users", "id": "1" } }, "tags": { "data": [{ "type": "tags", "id": "2" }] } }
        },
        {
            "type": "discussions",
            "id": "39",
            "attributes": {
                "title": "Discussion",
                "slug": "39-discussion",
                "commentCount": 21,
                "participantCount": 1,
                "createdAt": "2021-05-22T11:06:43+00:00",
                "lastPostedAt": "2021-09-04T12:49:32+00:00",
                "lastPostNumber": 28,
                "canReply": true,
                "canRename": true,
                "canDelete": true,
                "canHide": true,
                "lastReadAt": "2021-09-04T12:49:34+00:00",
                "lastReadPostNumber": 28,
                "isApproved": true,
                "canTag": true,
                "subscription": null,
                "isLocked": false,
                "canLock": true
            },
            "relationships": { "user": { "data": { "type": "users", "id": "1" } }, "lastPostedUser": { "data": { "type": "users", "id": "1" } }, "tags": { "data": [{ "type": "tags", "id": "1" }] } }
        }
```

what i want to do is to have something like "related content" based on a discussion title. For example if i have this title "lets talk about cars", the json must shows all the discussions related to this title.

is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can take the `data` from json and just filter the content inside

```
const filteredResults = yourJsonResponse.data.filter(item => item.attributes.title === 'lets talk about cars')
```

Comment: that could be definitely a solution....thanks

Answer (score 1):

This won't be a good idea. as you're getting paginated list with limit(like per page 20/30). if you're using js you can use js filter for getting related content. But as i said. that filer will be done based on your current page data, not all data. it's better to use another api end for related content from large data..

Comment: but i can filter this output to last 20 discussions...so canbe useful...right?

Comment: Yes you can filter on those 20 discussions like Ervis Hajdari mentioned.